# Most accurate method to find exoplanets?

Tags: nasa, space-telescope, planet, exoplanet

NASA has found thousands of exoplanets in space using their powerful telescopes. How exactly does NASA do so and what is the best method? I'm assuming that NASA uses some sort of sensor to detect anomalies in the space background to find planets. But is there a reliable and accurate way to confirm the planet exists?

Additionally, there could be [false positives as suggested by this paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018AAS...23212009L/abstract) from Harvard.

Comment: near duplicate https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21556/how-was-the-first-exoplanet-detected/21562#21562 and related wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_exoplanet_firsts.

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exoplanet and follow the links to Transit photometry and Doppler spectroscopy.

Comment: @dialFrost, there is actually several questions, the 'how do we find exoplanets' is not really a good stack exchange question since there are now many many ways, per those two lists of 'firsts'. NASA actually does little astronomy themselves. It may be better to do an edit to narrow the focus of the question to either NASA work, or to ask the 'most accurate' - most methods are working indirectly to infer the presence of a planet but believe there have now been direct images taken.

Comment: Do you want to know the most accurate single method, or the planet that has been detected the most accurately - has been confirmed by multiple methods?

Comment: Most accurate single method @GremlinWranger

Comment: If you don't afraid of longreads: here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350341313_The_TESS_Objects_of_Interest_Catalog_from_the_TESS_Prime_Mission - is TESS prime mission results. See chapters 2-7 for data aquisition, analysis and false positives exclusion.

Comment: About another method - radial velocity exoplanet search: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04644 - see chapter 3 for methods, including false positive exclusion.

Comment: If you want you can make an answer! :3 Make sure to confirm that not only do they exclude false-positives, but they're also more accurate and reliable than the others. Thanks